# Apache Redirect for Internal Traffic Only

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2, url-rewriting

We have a page, gateway.school.edu, where users have to fill out a recaptcha before being directed forward to our password reset. I would like any internal traffic, any user agent on our network with a 10.*, 172.* or 192.* IP, to get passed through without having to fill out the recaptcha. So an internal user would navigate to gateway.school.edu, where apache would check for an internal IP, then send them on to reset.school.edu. External users would have to fill out the captcha before being sent to reset.school.edu

Is this possible using {REMOTE_ADDR} in apache? Something like:

```
#gateway.school.edu virtual host
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192.*
RewriteRule .* reset.school.edu
```

Is there another approach I could take to accomplish this, or would a rewrite be the best way?
Syntactically, how do I define the IP ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer:

```
#gateway.school.edu virtual host
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\.(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^172\.(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.(.*)$
RewriteRule .* reset.school.edu [R=301,L]
```